# The difference between Training Area and Training Box

Tags: meaning

Can anyone tell me the difference between the terms " Training Area " and "Training Box " in a military context ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Note that we are equipped to handle questions about general usage, but for industry or professional jargon, you will get more reliable answers by asking in a forum where people working in that industry or occupation will be found. This is important as the common understanding or a word or phrase may differ considerably from the way it is understood by practitioners.

Answer (score 3):

A training box used to be a reference to a sand box or sand pit.  The Oxford English Dictionary has a reference which clarifies the point:

> 1971 J. Wainwright *Last Buccaneer* II. 243 'What... is a sand table?' 'It's usually a tray filled with sand.  The army uses them.  It's possible to mould the sand into the contours of geographic locations for demonstrating military tactics.'

A training area (in military terms) refers to a real-world location which may have (but not necessarily) been chosen for its resemblance to an expected deployment zone.  Over time the usages have been blurred (see this US Army website: http://v-e-n-u-e.com/In-the-Box-A-Tour-Through-the-Simulated-Battlefields-of-the-U-S-Army).

Colloquially the Middle East has been referred to as the 'Sand Box', which may be an  oblique (and ironic) reference to it becoming a training area for US tactics and strategy - and it being full of sand.  But essentially, a training box suggests a 'model' wherein the parameters can be changed, whereas a training area is a 'boots on the ground' training facility.